# Waterline Query - startWith anything other than a letter?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I have a query whereby I pass a letter and it gets the relevant information from the database as can be found here:

```
        where: {
            'salesRank' : {
            ">" : req.body.highest, "<" : req.body.lowest
        },
        'brand': {
            startsWith: req.body.alphabet
        }},
        sort: 'salesRank ASC'
    }
```

On my form however, I also have an option which allows for anything that is not a letter.  So numbers, special characters etc.

What I need to be able to do is say, if req.body.alphabet is '#' then:

```
        'brand': {
            startsWith: //Anything that is not a letter
        }}
```

Unfortunately I have no idea where to even start with this.  Can anyone assist me please?

Answer (score -1):

```
'brand': {
            startsWith: req.body.yourQueryData.toString()
        }}
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question.  What is being passed from the form is irrelevant.  I need to know how to query startWith anything that is a number or special character